# Pygame: Text losing anti-aliasing when blitting to SRCALPHA surface

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I recently changed the way my pygame game handles menus. Any text I'm rendering is blit to a surface called `guiSurface` before it is blit to the display (`screen`).
The problem is that this causes the text to appear aliased, whereas blitting it directly to the display didn't have this issue.

With `guiSurface` [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff37S.png):

```
        menuFont = pygame.font.Font('assets/MarkPro.otf',15,bold=False,italic=False)
        menuText = menuFont.render(version, 1, (255,255,255))
        guiSurface.blit(menuText,(790-(menuText.get_size()[0]),475))

        screen.blit(guiSurface, (0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
```

Directly to display [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbnEJ.png):

```
        menuFont = pygame.font.Font('assets/MarkPro.otf',15,bold=False,italic=False)
        menuText = menuFont.render(version, 1, (255,255,255))
        screen.blit(menuText,(790-(menuText.get_size()[0]),475))

        screen.blit(guiSurface, (0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
```

I've tried using `.convert()` and `.convert_alpha()` on both the `menuText` and `guiSurface` surfaces, after line 2 in both code snippets, but to no avail. And I have no idea at which point the anti-aliasing is lost.

Help is of course appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fault is mine. I didn't clear `guiSurface` after blitting it to the display, meaning I was drawing over what was already there instead of a fresh surface.